# The type or namespace name 'Scene' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It's my first time asking a question here. I started programming in UNITY 3D just recently, so my question can be very common, but I really can't find any answers to it.

I'm watching a tutorial on YouTube and copying the same code. Everything is the same as in the video, but the author doesn't have any problems with it, while I have, I checked the code 10 times, and here is the problem in the question title.

Thank you in advance for your support!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameManager instance;
    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }
    // Resourses 
    public List<Sprite> playerSprites;
    public List<Sprite> weaponSprites;
    public List<int> weaponPrices;
    public List<int> xpTable;

    // References

    public Player player;

    //private weapon weapon...

    //Logic
    public int pesos;
    public int experience;

    // SaveState
    /*
     * INT preferedSkin
     * INT pesos
     * INT experience
     * INT weaponLevel
     *
     */
    public void SaveState()
    {
        string s = "";
        
        s += "0" + "|";
        s += pesos.ToString() + "|";
        s += experience.ToString() + "|";
        s += "0";

        PlayerPrefs.SetString("SaveState", s);
    }
    public void LoadState(Scene s, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        if(!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("SaveState"))
        {
            return;
        }
        
        string[] data = PlayerPrefs.GetString("SaveState").Split('|');
        
        // Change player skin
        pesos = int.Parse(data[1]);
        experience = int.Parse(data[2]);
        // Change the weapon Level
        
        Debug.Log("LoadState");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scene is apart of the the SceneManagment namespace. Try adding:

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
```

source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene.html

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a package reference. A google search tells me that `Scene` class is implemented in `UnityEngine.CoreModule` so try adding it at the top:

```
using UnityEngine.CoreModule
```

If you are using Visual Studio you can place the cursor on `Scene` and hit `crtl` + `.` for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the "fully qualifying namespace" as such

```
public void LoadState(UnityEngine.SceneManagement.Scene s, LoadSceneMode mode)
```

or import the library by including `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;` at the top which you can easily access in Visual Studio by Holding down CTRL and pressing ( . ) and it's usually the first option but make sure first that your curser is resting on the erroneous part of the code